# Electron window fit content width and height

Tags: ionic-framework, electron, ionic4

I'm developing an application with `Electron` and `Ionic 4` and i would like to set the window size (BrowserWindow object) in order to fit content width and height of the home page, as i would do in `java swing` by calling `JFrame pack` method.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm in a similar situation. i.e. I'd like the Electron to fit the html content. Plus if I show other content (e.g. div.hidden = false) I'd like the Electron Window to expand.

Best solution I've found so far is to send a event indicating a resize and handle that in the main process.

https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-re-size-electron-main-window-dynamically/48183/3

Neater solutions would be welcome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm assuming you suggest to calculate first desidered width and height and resizing using that dimension?

Comment: That's one approach. For me once I show the hidden div I can then get the 'content' width and height and use that to resize.